# amazon redshift single sign or service account approach

Tags: amazon-web-services, single-sign-on, amazon-redshift

Does anybody know if it is possible to access Amazon Redshift via single sign on or service accounts. Our specific need is to map domain users to Redshift users, and then grant access to specific objects to this mapped users, so if a user wants to query Redhisft via some SQL client or some Excel connector (for example) he can use his domain credentials without having to store or type passwords on every connector. I know the existence of AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) but from my understanding this works just for SSO to the management console, am i right?

Answer (score 2):

AWS has recently announced the support for Federated authentication with single sign-on support for Redshift.

[Using IAM Authentication to Generate Database User Credentials for AWS Redshift](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/generating-user-credentials.html)

I am currently trying to implement it and will update this answer once I am done with the setup.